# Как использовать переменную одной функции в другой функции?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Мне нужно использовать переменную одной функции в другой функции, как я должен перестроить синтаксис, чтобы получить верное выражение?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget, plot
import pyqtgraph as pg
import functions as fn
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    h = 1.055 * (10 ** (-34))  # Планка, Джоули
    m = 9.1 * (pow(10, -31))  # Масса электрона, кг
    pi = 3.14  # Число ПИ
    index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Загрузите страницу интерфейса
        uic.loadUi('ain.ui', self)
        #A=self.lineEdit.text()
        self.EnergyHistogram()
        #self.plotBarChart()
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.EnergyTable)




    # мы добавили метод plot(), который принимает два массива:
    # temperature и hour, затем строит данные с помощью метода graphWidget.plot().

    def plot(self):
        #grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.graphWidget)
        #grid.addWidget(self.graphWidget, 0, 0)
        #self.graphWidget.plot(a,b=2)
        pass
    def check(self):
        A = self.lineEdit.text()

    def EnergyTable(self):
        n = 5
        i = 0
        E = np.arange(n, dtype=float)
        A = int(self.lineEdit.text()) * pow(10, -9)
        for i in range(n):
            E[i] = (pow(self.pi, 2) * pow(self.h, 2) * pow(i + 1, 2)) / (2 * self.m * pow(A, 2))
        E_J = EnergyTable()
        E_erg, E_ev = 0, 0
        E_erg = fn.ERG(E_J)
        E_eV = fn.eV(E_J)
        table = {'Дж': E_J, 'эрг': E_erg, '  эВ': E_eV}
        df = pd.DataFrame(table, index=self.index)
        df = str(df)
        self.label.setText(df)
        return E_J

    def EnergyHistogram(self):
        E_J=
        bg1 = pg.BarGraphItem(x=self.index, height=self.E_J, width=0.6, brush='r')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Нужно взять учебник и узнать, что делает return  в функции. Это самые азы. Заодно выяснить, что E_J в одной функции и E_J в другой функции - совершенно разные вещи.

Comment: Опубликуйте модуль `ain.ui`. Скажите что такое `E_J` и его значение при инициализации.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получить значение функции, Вам необходимо её для начала вызвать.
Назначить переменной значение возвращаемой переменной.
И уже в дальнейшем её использовать.

```py
def EnergyTable(self):
    n = 5
    i = 0
    E = np.arange(n, dtype=float)
    A = int(self.lineEdit.text()) * pow(10, -9)
    for i in range(n):
        E[i] = (pow(self.pi, 2) * pow(self.h, 2) * pow(i + 1, 2)) / (2 * self.m * pow(A, 2))
    E_J = E
    E_erg, E_ev = 0, 0
    E_erg = fn.ERG(E_J)
    E_eV = fn.eV(E_J)
    index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    table = {'Дж': E_J, 'эрг': E_erg, '  эВ': E_eV}
    df = pd.DataFrame(table, index=index)
    df = str(df)
    self.label.setText(df)
    return E_J

def EnergyHistogram(self):
    E_J = EnergyTable(param)
    bg1 = pg.BarGraphItem(x=self.index, height=E_J, width=0.6, brush='r')
```

Где `param` - это параметр который Вы передаёте в функцию `EnergyTable`.

Comment: Конкретно param можно подробнее? зачем этот параметр я должен передать в EnergyTable? И какое значение нужно ввести, чтобы получить E_J из предыдущей функции?

Comment: @steam-ilka Функция `EnergyTable` ожидает передачи параметра `self`, соответственно Вам необходимо передать данный параметр в вызов функции. Так как Вы этот же параметр передаёте и во вторую функцию - Вы можете использовать `E_J = EnergyTable(self)`.

Comment: выдает ошибку.. Там в скобках ничего писать не нужно, вроде. Потому что программе кажется, что я передаю 2 аргумента. Пытался перед функцией ставить self.EnergyTable(), тоже ошибка..

Comment: @steam-ilka Как я писал ранее, функция `EnergyTable` ожидает параметра `self`, Как Вы получаете и используете этот параметр - осталось за "кадром" предоставленного примера. Если у Вас функцию идут таким же образом, как и указано, то данный параметр должен передаваться из сущности, из которой Вы вызываете данную функцию. Это же тоже самое, что и `this` в других языках, просто непонятно, откуда именно Вы хотите передать туда параметр.

Comment: ,Я добавил полный код, каким образом я сейчас должен поступить?

Answer (score 0):

Сложно говорить наверняка, не видя всего кода.

Но, кажется, можно просто заменить

```
return E_J
```

на

```
self.E_J = E_J
```

Comment: А как потом обращаться к этой переменной в другой функции?

Comment: Так же, как у вас это сейчас происходит - через self. Вообще, вам конечно стоит почитать про классы и как они работают, раз уж вы ими пользуетесь.

Comment: Не работает, как вы предложили..
Так я уже пробовал..

Comment: Не работает, потому что у вас в остальном коде полный бардак. Там нужно всё полностью переписывать. Во первых, вы эти два метода нигде не вызываете. Во-вторых, вы внутри метода EnergyTable пытаетесь использовать EnergyTable.

Comment: Первый метод вызывается по кнопке